# JQuery - trigger change when change is made manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div>
   <label>Location</label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="Location" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Enter location"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    <label >Address</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"    ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Enter the address"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Address is Required" Display="Dynamic"  ControlToValidate="Address" CssClass="field-validation-error" EnableClientScript="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />  

<script>
    $("#Location").on('change', function (e) {
        var location =  $("#Location").val();
        $("#Address").val(location).trigger("change");
    });

    $("#Address").on('change', function (e) {
        // do some other stuff
    });
</script>
```

The Address field is populated via jQuery with the value of the Location field.

If I click submit without filling in any fields, the client side validation kicks in and we get the error message displayed below the Address control.

If I now enter a value into the Location field, the jQuery fires and the Address field is populated with a value but the previous error message doesn't clear. To solve this I use `.trigger("change");` method.

However each time I use `.trigger("change")` it calls it also fires the following function:

```
$("#Address").on('change', function (e) {
    // do some other stuff
});
```

I only want to fire the address on change event handler only when the input is changed manually and not by jQuery.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where does your error message get displayed. Does it add an attribute to the input when it errors.

Answer (score 0):

*input is changed manually* then don't bind the change event handler at all.

You should bind the event handler when you are changing the value manually and the use `.off()` to remove the event listener.

```js
function AddressEventHandler(e) {
  // do some other stuff
}

$("#Location").on('change', function(e) {
  var location = $("#Location").val();

  $("#Address").val(location)
    .on('change.myNamespace', AddressEventHandler)
    .trigger("change.myNamespace")
    .off('change.myNamespace');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix by doing the following:

```
$("#Address").on('change', function (e) {

    if (e.originalEvent !== undefined)
    {
       // do some other stuff
     }

});
```